# Вывод логов на экран в Unity на платформу Android

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно вывести все логи Unity на экран в Android? или по нажатию на кнопки открывать файл с логами который в Android создается

Comment: Не совсем понял о чем идет речь, но если нужно выводить сообщения, которые Вы сами бросаете с помощью Debug.Log(), то Вам поможет `void MonoBehaviour.OnUnhendeledException(string condition, string stackTrace, LogType type)`, где `type` будет равен `LogType.Log`.

Comment: Использовал утилиту https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/log-viewer-12047